# How to add breadcrumbs on custom phtml page?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, breadcrumbs

How to display breadcrumbs on custom phtml page in magento 1?

How to define breadcrumbs in layout xml or config file of custom module?

Please give me suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add breadcrumbs from your custom index controller action. Reference code is below.

```
public function IndexAction() {      
  $this->loadLayout();
  $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Magento Developer"));  /* add your page title */
        $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs");
  $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("home", array(
            "label" => $this->__("Home Page"),
            "title" => $this->__("Home Page"),
            "link"  => Mage::getBaseUrl()
       ));

  $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("magento_developer", array(       /* add css class */
            "label" => $this->__("Magento Developer"),
            "title" => $this->__("Magento Developer")
       ));

  $this->renderLayout(); 

}
```